# What is the official way to deal with string in C++/FORTRAN interop

Tags: c++, string, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'd like to learn the latest improvement in C++/FORTRAN interoperability when it comes to string in particular. The following is my unsuccessful attempt, please help me correct or advise a better solution.
My compiler is gcc 4.8.5

In C++

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"{
    void SayHello(char*);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char * name = argv[1];
    SayHello(name);
    return 0;
}
```

In Fortran

```
module MyModule

      contains
          subroutine SayHello(people) bind(c,name="SayHello")
              use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
              character, dimension(50), intent(in) :: people
              write(*,*) "Hello ", people
          end subroutine
end module MyModule
```

Comment: Why is your attempt unsuccessful?  You will certainly have a problem if `argv[1]` isn't at least length 50. That is, please show any errors or messages.

Comment: For a reason I don't know why (read: the reason why I am here), I got the following compilation error with codes above https://pastebin.com/Q4e48RkV

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++, but in the C version I posted in my answer, printing is left to the Fortran program. Do you need `std::cout`?

Comment: oops, I'll correct that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `c_char` type:

`character(kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(in)`

---

**EDIT 1**
So, after @francescalus posed the question, I looked into this further. Basically, the "assumed size" character array is not necessary<sup>**1**</sup>, although I do believe that the size of the char array is (please correct me if I'm wrong about that). I'm going to post a C-calling-Fortran version below, since I don't know the C++ syntax and don't feel like looking it up.

---

**EDIT 2**
As mentioned in footnote 1, it is only correct to declare `people` in the Fortran program as an assumed size array of chars, or (as suggested by @VladimirF) with the size given directly by `sz`. I clear this up in the code below.

The Fortran program:

```
! SayHello.f90
subroutine SayHello(people,sz) bind(c,name="SayHello")
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    ! Notes: 
    ! The size `sz` of the character array is passed in by value.
    ! Declare `people` as an assumed-size array for correctness, or just use the size `sz` passed in from C.
    character(kind=c_char), intent(in), dimension(sz) :: people
    integer(kind=c_int), intent(in), value :: sz
    write(*,*) "Hello, ", people(1:sz)
end subroutine
```

And the C program:

```
/*Hello.c */    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void SayHello(char *name, int len);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    size_t sz = strlen(argv[1]);
    char * name = malloc(sz+1);
    strcpy(name, argv[1]);
    SayHello(name, sz+1);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation (with ifort), call, and output:

```
ifort /c SayHello.f90 
icl Hello.c /link SayHello.obj
Hello.exe MattP
// output: Hello, MattP
```

<sub><sup>**1**</sup>Update: Seems like the official usage "for interoperability" is to declare as an array of characters, using assumed size: `char(len=1,kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(in)`</sub>

Comment: gfortran -c mymodule.f90 
mymodule.f90:7.34:

              write(*,*) "Hello ", people
                                  1
Error: The upper bound in the last dimension must appear in the reference to the assumed size array 'people' at (1)
mymodule.f90:7.41:

              write(*,*) "Hello ", people
                                         1
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot be a full reference to an assumed-size array

Comment: @fanhako, although this answer doesn't address it, you should be aware that `people` is an assumed size array of length-1 characters, not a scalar assumed length character.  With an assumed size array you cannot (as the compiler complains) reference it as a whole array.  You need to change much more than just the one declaration.

Comment: Can you explain why declaration of an explicit shape array should be changed to one of an assumed size array?

Comment: @francescalus Wellll...turns out, you *don't* need to do that. But as you mention, you do need the size of the character array. See my edit.

Comment: @francescalus Oh, the comment above is the compiler output when I tried Matt's suggested modification. I am really confused about the difference of array of char in these two languages. And I am just limiting myself to C char*, how about C++ standard string ? I am here to learn, so would you tell me more about "change much more than just the one declaration" ?

Comment: @fanhako Did you try the solution in the edited answer? You need to change a few things about the Fortran code (also, read the notes in the code).

Comment: You aren't passing the size of character array (or the length of the character scalar): `character(kind=c_char), intent(in) :: people` is a scalar length-1 character without a `dimension` statement.  `people(1:sz)` is an invalid substring reference for `sz` greater than 1 in this case (or invalid array reference for the scalar).

Comment: @MattP: Thanks, your explanation was clear! I edited the code in C++, now it's working. Next step for me is to return a value

Comment: @francescalus I think that you are correct: `character(len=1,kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(in) :: people` is prob the most technically correct. However, `sz` is most certainly the size (number of items) of the char array.

Comment: The program is invalid.

Comment: Ah, there you are @VladimirF! Could you be more specific?

Comment: Just move the correct code from the comment to the real code. `character(kind=c_char), intent(in) :: people` is invalid, because you then do `people(1:sz)`. The `character(kind=c_char), intent(in), dimension(*) :: people` or even better `character(kind=c_char), intent(in), dimension(sz) :: people` is necessary.

Comment: Compile with `-fcheck=all` to see.

Comment: @VladimirF Agreed! Done. Should have made that change earlier.